# Как выровнять элемент по центру с помощью bootstrap сетки?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть вот такой `row` с текстом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам текст занимает всего 4 колонки по сетке Bootstrap, если я прописываю блоку с данным текстом `class='col-4'`, то элемент занимает первые 4 колонки слева, а мне нужно выровнять по середине, как это можно сделать? Использую только сетку Bootstrap4. Пробовал задавать класс `class='col-12'` после чего задавать блоку с текстом `text-align: center;`, но считаю, что это не правильно. Т.к. если бы это был, например, блок с границами, то он растянулся бы на все 12 колонок.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section class="your_invetnory">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-4 inventory_before_after">
        <h3>Ваш инвентарь до и после</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: [Вот здесь](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment) написано

Comment: @fanfer, пробовал до этого, не получается, остается на том же месте по какой-то причине.

Comment: Додайте `.justify-content-center`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wodh7m5n/1/

Comment: @fanfer, делаю все точно так же, не могу понять, почему у меня не работает.

Comment: значит не так же. я без кода не могу понять что не так

Comment: @fanfer, Приложил код

Comment: @entithat, конкретно у меня - нет, может я не ту версию сетки скачал, или может этот класс есть конкретно у всего бутстрапа, а не только у сетки?

Comment: @entithat, так и делал

Comment: @entithat, видимо в этом и проблема, что в одних лишь гридах - нет этих классов.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, скорее всего, что, да, нету. Почему Вы не хотите использовать полною версию? **UPD посмотрел в исходный код `bootsrap-grid.css`, оказалось, что класс `.justify-...` есть!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section class="your_invetnory">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-4 inventory_before_after">
        <h3>Ваш инвентарь до и после</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```